# How to test observable returned by throwError in catchError operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jasmine

I have a function which adds operators to an observable returned by a command dispatch. I have added `catchError` which will convert the caught error into one of my error types. Source observable is subscribed within the function and is not visible to outside. Functionality is working fine, but I am having trouble writing the unit tests for this, since code inside the function is async but execution of the async code is not visible outside the function scope.

```html
doStuff() {
        commandService.dispatch( 'MyCommand', { data: data }).pipe(
            catchError( error => throwError( new MyError())),
            last(),
            tap( resultData => {
                processResultData( resultData );
            }),
        ).subscribe();
}
```

Following is the unit test I have written.

```html
it( 'should not call processResult if error', async done => {
            const error = { code: 1608, message: 'error', name: 'error' };
            spyOn( commandService, 'dispatch' ).and.returnValue( throwError( error ));
            spyOn(  myObject, 'processResult' ).and.returnValue( of({}));
            myObject.doStuff();
            expect(() => myObject.processResult ).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
```

This test is failing since the error thrown by `throwError` inside the `catchError` has not been handled. Test complaints that unexpected error occurred. I tried couple of ways to catch the error but was not successful. Is there any way to catch the thrown error without exposing the observable to outside of function?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your doStuff function like so:

```
doStuff() {
        commandService.dispatch( 'MyCommand', { data: data }).pipe(
            catchError( error => throwError( new MyError())),
            last(),
            tap( resultData => {
                processResultData( resultData );
            }),
         ).subscribe(success => {
           // ... what happens on success, keep it blank
       }, error => {
         // ... what happens on error, keep it blank
       });
}
```

I think adding that error function handler in the subscribe block should get rid of that error (now the error should be getting caught).